# How to know if an imagefound on google has copyright

Tags: image

Hi evryone I am working on a recipes website, I need to use recipes image i search the image on google but how can i know if the images have copyright? I look at free use image website but I need specific images of recipes and in these sites I often do not find them

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Image search tools to filter the images by license :
[image]